# Mac OS 10.13.2: Internet Sharing for multiple bridges

Tags: networking, macos, macos-highsierra, bridging

I have a macpro with two 802.3(`en0` and `en1`) interfaces and wifi(`en2`).

I have created AX88x72A interface(`en11`) for my Ethernet over USB device.

I have following internet sharing settings:

[image]

This creates the `bridge100` interface with IP of 172.16.42.1 which bridges all checked interfaces: Ethernet1(`en0`), Ethernet2(`en1`) and AX88x72A(`en11`)

I want the following:

- `bridge100` with static ip 172.16.42.1 with only Ethernet2(`en1`) and AX88x72A(`en11`) to share internet connection with all devices connected to that interfaces.
- `en0` to have static ip 192.168.2.1 and also share the internet connection with devices connected to this interface.
- Both `bridge100` and `en0` has to have dhcp(or bootp) running so they give out the ip addresses to connected devices

I am not sure, maybe I can create two bridges somehow...
Please give me some advices... I know I should be able to achieve this somehow...
Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Seems like the `bridge100` is a very special bridge.

Although I have `en0` with static IP 192.168.2.1, I still can not find a way to share internet on this interface without adding it to `bridge100` by checking it in **Preferences > Sharing > Internet Sharing**

However, when I add `en0` to Internet Sharing (technically to `bridge100`), the only accessible ip is 172.16.42.1 - address of bridge which is set in `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat.plist`, ignoring the GUI settings for Ethernet 1 (`en0`):
[image]

It seems like impossible to have multiple bridged interfaces with 2 different ip addresses for internet sharing on MacOS. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I have found so far is the following:

- add all three physical interfaces (`en0`, `en1` and `en11`) to `bridge100` in GUI (**Preferences  > Sharing > Internet Sharing**)
- Alter the file */Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat.plist*
  using defaults commands:

  `$ sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat NAT -dict-add SharingNetworkNumberStart 172.16.42.0`

  `$ sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat NAT -dict-add SharingNetworkNumberEnd 172.16.42.254`

  `$ sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat NAT -dict-add SharingNetworkMask 255.255.255.0`
- Start `bridge100` with the ip 172.16.42.1:

  `$ sudo ifconfig bridge100 172.16.42.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up`
- And add alias (second ip) to `bridge100`:
  `$ sudo ifconfig bridge100 alias 192.168.2.1`

In this case our `bridge100` will have 2 ip addresses but of course it will act as a dhcp only with range 172.16.42.0/24